# How do I take a scene-object popup window, and use instances of a prefab button to initiate it?

Tags: unity

I have a button that invokes a modal window (a market transaction). Using the inspector `onclick`, I have successfully setup so that 1 of the 9 buttons will pop the window (`GameObject.SetActive ✅`), and then the Done button in the window will close it ().

However there are 9 of these buttons, and they use a prefab for their design.

Here's a pic of the hierarchy with the button instance highlighted:

[image]

Each `rowItem` is the exact same (from a `rowItem` prefab). Also, each row has data that needs to be passed into the modal. An index would probably be enough.

How do I setup the prefab so that the 9 instanced buttons invoke the popup and pass the data?

I'm a JS webdev by day, so I generally understand the concepts. I'm just newbie on the syntax and where everything is in Unity.

Comment: Please add images directly to your question (which uses Stack's built-in hosting) rather than linking to 3rd party hosting as it helps prevent link rot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but if you want to get the index of the button you pressed, you can do something like this:

```
public class MarketTable : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private IndexedButton buttonPrefab;
    private List<IndexedButton> buttons;

    void Awake() {
        AddButtons();
    }

    void AddButtons() {
        buttons = new List<Button>(9);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            var button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
            button.Index = i;
            buttons.Add(button);
            button.ClickEvent.AddListener(OnClickButton);
        }
    }

    void OnClickButton(IndexedButton button) {
        int index = button.Index;
        //do something with the index here
    }
}

[System.Serializable] public class IndexedButtonEvent : UnityEvent<IndexedButton>

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button)]
public class IndexedButton : MonoBehavior {
    [SerializeField] private IndexedButtonEvent clickedEvent = new IndexedButtonEvent();

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public IndexedButtonEvent ClickedEvent => clickedEvent;

    void Awake() {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(button);
        button.onClick.AddListener(OnClickButton);
    }

    void OnClickButton() {
        clickedEvent.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Here we've created a custom component for the Market Table UI panel and a custom component for our buttons. We add the `IndexedButton` component to our button prefab. When we instantiate a button, we set its index. When we click a button, the button's `ClickedEvent` is invoked, which calls the `OnClickButton()` function with a reference to the button that was clicked. We can then check the index on the button.

You could also replace the `Index` property with some other type of data that you want to associate with the button.